# player.getPlayerState is unavailable after YouTube Iframe API initialization

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

A feature using the YouTube Iframe API has been broken for a while on a little music discovery site I have, and I'm trying to understand why:

1. Open [www.dailygrooves.org](http://www.dailygrooves.org/)
2. Press the `spacebar` key.

*→ Expected*: playback should start.

*→ Actual*: the `playpause` function throws `TypeError: player.getPlayerState is not a function` when running `var playerState = player.getPlayerState()`. And looking at my player object, indeed this method is missing:

[image: screenshot of the 'player' object in my DevTools]

What's wrong in my API usage / initialization? It used to work fine, and I think started to fail a few months ago, even though the [YouTube Iframe Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) mentions no recent changes to the API. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try suggestion mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637991/youtube-iframe-player-js-api-with-jquery-player-object-has-no-method-getplaye

Comment: @DCrystal yes, I instantiate the player with `player = new YT.Player('playeriframe')`, and `playeriframe` is the id of my iframe.

Comment: Hoping to help others: for me what was causing this error was I had 2 videos with the same ID in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
enablejsapi=1
```

to the iframe 'src' attribute. E.g.:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?wmode=opaque&autohide=0&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1&list="
```

Comment: Grargh, I thought I tried that. Must have borked the deployment when I tried, or got bitten by caching. Anyway, it works! Hats off to you, thanks :)

Comment: enablejsapi=1 is already added but still getting error
I am using this src https://www.youtube.com/embed/q_0uF80IZXM?enablejsapi=1