# YT getPlayerState() not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I need to access the YouTube states through JS to control a video slideshow. For some reason I am getting the `getPlayerState()` is not a function messages. I can access the `playerState` property directly though I would like to do it the 'correct' way as stated in the docs. Does anyone know what issue may be causing this?

Pertinent code:

```
if (window.YTIframeAPIReady) {
  ytPlayers[this.id] = new YT.Player(this.id, {
    events: {
      'onStateChange': youtubeStateChange,
    }
  }
}

function youtubeStateChange(event) {
  // This returns the player state.
  console.log(event.target.v.playerState);
  // This returns Uncaught TypeError: event.target.getPlayerState is not a function
  console.log(event.target.getPlayerState());
}
```

I have similar code in another part of the site that still seems to be working with the `getPlayerState()` so I am a bit stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: Please try the solution given in this SO post - [Youtube iframe player JS API with jQuery - player object has no method 'getPlayerState'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637991/youtube-iframe-player-js-api-with-jquery-player-object-has-no-method-getplaye). I hope that also covers your issue.

Comment: @Teyam `this.id` is the id of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You have do a check to see if getPlayerState is a function.

`getPlayerState()` is a number, which makes it even more fun!

For example:

```
if (typeof players[0].getPlayerState === "function") {
    console.log(event.target.getPlayerState());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had completely forgot about this question. I know the issue is that the getPlayerState is not a function yet. I got around the issue by doing a check similar to yours in a timeout loop. I would still like to know why the value is there if you dig in to the object but the function is not available.