# Youtube Iframe api player.getPlayerState and player.getCurrentTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am following the youtube [iframe api reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)
Here is how I initialize my player(in onYouTubeIframeAPIReady)

```
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            playerVars: {
                modestbranding: 1,
                controls: controls,
                frameborder: 0,
                autoplay: 1,
                autohide: 1,
                showinfo: 0,                %{-- with showinfo set to 0, the modestbranding setting doesn't work --}%
                rel: 0,
                start: startOffset,
            },
            videoId: someVideoId,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            },
```

I am using a div to render the player(not an embedded iframe):

```
<div id="video-container" style="display:none;">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is that whenever I try to use functions `player.getPlayerState` and `player.getCurrentTime` I get error that these functions don't exist on player object.
On some further research, I found that we need to have the `enablejsapi` parameter set to `1` in the video embed url (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649345/1291122)). But since I am not using an iframe, this is ruled out. (I can not use iframe because my video url is dynamic).

The documentation suggest that `playerVars` while initializing the player has `enablejsapi` [parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#enablejsapi) but this too does not work and I still get this error.

The generated iframe using playerVars while initialization does not contain the `enablejsapi` parameter in `src` attribute.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact err and what you going to achieve? Please explain

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic url ?

Comment: @Novice dynamic url means the url can change at runtime in browser.